# How do I convert between rfc-2822 time zones?

Tags: python-3.x

I have datetimes in RFC 2822 format such as:

`Wed, 06 Oct 2021 23:45:05 +0000 (UTC)`

and using email.utils to parse it.

But I would like to convert the zone to PDT (-0700) before parsing it.

How can that be done in Python 3.9 ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Technically you need to parse it *before* you can change it to pdt.

```
timestring = "Wed, 06 Oct 2021 23:45:05 +0000 (UTC)"

import email, pytz
t = email.utils.parsedate_to_datetime(timestring)
pdttime = t.astimezone(pytz.timezone('US/PACIFIC'))
print(email.utils.format_datetime(pdttime))
```